# How do I override belongs_to getter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models like this:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

The problem is my company made an "informed decision" to allow duplicate IDs in all db records. So if I call something like this:

```
my_bar.foo
```

If there are multiple `Foo` records with the same id, then that call will return the wrong one, because the SQL query from the association getter is:

```
 SELECT  `foos`.* FROM `foos` WHERE `foos`.`id` = 2625196 LIMIT 1
```

So I want to update my association getter to something like this:

```
class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
  def foo
    Foo.where(id: foo_id, user_id: current_user.id).first
  end
end
```

That *kind of* works, but doesn't work for unsaved records, and forces an SQL query every time.

#### Question

How can I properly override an association getter?

Comment: So now you have two-way has_many associations? I would rather rewrite this and make a join table... or maybe set a different primary key in the migration

Comment: You must be using a composite primary key if multiple records can have the same id, no? If not, how to override an association getter is the least of your problems.

Comment: @MarkMerritt oh I am very aware of the incoming problems. But duplicate IDs it is—not allowed to change that now. So the question is, how do I work with what I've got?

Comment: @Mirror318 instead of trying to override the association, you could create a scope (class method) on Foo. Just try your best to isolate the problem to as few classes/models as possible. Go into damage control mode.

Comment: It's a really bad practice to reference the "current_user" on a model method (models shouldn't know about the request context). I think you are looking for the wrong design solution and that's why it's hard to do, it sounds like you actually want a join model and a many to many relationship.